# Reading Netflow v9 packets in Python

Tags: python, netflow

I'm trying to write a collector which listens to incoming Netflow v9 packets on a UDP port and unpacks the records and calculates the total number of bytes.

I have a sample collection of data (which I recorded with `nfcapd`): When I analyse this data with `nfdump` then it comes to 8.2GB.

```
nfdump -r netflowv9.201911081650
```

When I transmit this data (locally) using `nfreplay`, my Python code finds only about half the data compared to `nfdump`, and that's even when I set `nfreplay` to replay the netflow really really slowly.

```
nfreplay -r netflowv9.201911081650 -v 9 -d 10000
```

And then also some of the time I get just bad data and my Python script seems to report several petabytes.

Any hints?

My code: https://pastebin.com/hubPJ6tA  (Just run it before the `nfreplay` as above. I'm using `pypy` 3.6)

My sample data: http://edward.filegooi.co.za/get2/f207e55ec37428e82d8ce91952fda85b/netflowv9.201911081650

Comment: what about https://pythonhosted.org/pynfdump/?

Comment: @ArcherGodson I'm trying to make a tool to read the netflow v9 directly. I'm just using nfdump for now to compare my sample collection totals to my own collected netflow totals.

Answer (score 0):

[python-ipfix](https://github.com/britram/python-ipfix) can process Netflow V9 packets as well as IPFIX (V10) packets, despite its name.

The [API documentation](https://britram.github.io/python-ipfix/) covers reading a stream from either a file or socket using the [`ipfix.reader`](https://britram.github.io/python-ipfix/#module-ipfix.reader) class. It does not mention the [`ipfix.v9pdu`](https://github.com/britram/python-ipfix/blob/master/ipfix/v9pdu.py) class, but this works in exactly the same way. There are good example of both the V9 and IPFIX in the included [ipfixstat script](https://github.com/britram/python-ipfix/blob/master/scripts/ipfixstat).

```
import ipfix.message
import ipfix.v9pdu


ipfix.reader.from_stream(open (args.file, mode="rb"))
```